# Carleman's conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

I compared Carleman's condition to Hadamard's radius of convergence for Taylor series.  Given that the MGF can be re-expressed as a taylor series (that can be extended to a strip in the complex plane under the hypothesis that the radius is $>0$), why is a specific condition tailored for a probabilistic problem only as good as a general condition furnished by complex analysis?  Is there some historical significance that makes Carleman's condition significant?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman's_condition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

(I am also reading from Durrett where the hadamard radius is not even mentioned, and yet a condition that is even more restrictive than Carleman's condition is given.)

To be clear, the implied reasoning in the Taylor series case is this: Suppose two distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ have the same moments for which the MGF exists and is finite in some neighborhood of $0$.  Then by the complex identity theorem, they have the same MGF, hence the same characteristic function, hence are equal.

In the comment I note that I was actually mistaken and Durrett's condition is equivalent to the Hadamard radius being finite, and the condition with Carleman's name on it is a bit weaker.  So I am modifying my questions to this: Is there a compelling reason to do something other than the complex analytic proof to see that the more restrictive assumption of Durrett that $limsup \mu_{2k}^{1/2k}<\infty$ suffices?  Where in the more difficult proof of Carleman implies determinateness of the moment problem does the specific setup and specific properties of the MGF allow it to beat the complex analytic approach?

Comment: Oh I was mistaken, it is actually Durrett's condition that is equivalent to Carlemann's condition.  He asks that $limsup \mu_{2k}^{1/2k}/2k<\infty$, which, by a less than full-blown version of Stirling, is equivalent.  So okay, the specific condition is a little better than the complex analysis one, but is that the only reason for its introduction?  Is there some probabilistic proof of the sufficiency of Carleman's condition that gives intuition into what's going on, specifically what it is about the specific probabilistic question that makes it possible to improve on the Hadamard approach?

Comment: `Carleman`with one `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carleman's condition is not *specific* to probability theory, and is very much part of complex analysis.

For a proof of Carleman's theorem, see Chapter 1 of *The Problem of moments* by J. A. Shohat and J. D. Tamarkin. The crux of the matter is that Carleman's series $\sum\limits_nm_n^{-1/n}$ diverges if and only if the integral $\int_1^\infty r^{-2}\log T(r)\,\mathrm dr$ diverges, where $T(r)=\sup\limits_nr^n/m_n$, and that the divergence of this integral implies that some specific holomorphic function measuring the difference between two solutions of the moments problem, is actually zero.
Thus, Carleman's condition implies the uniqueness of the solutions of the moments problem.

An example of a sequence of moments $(m_n)$ such that Carleman's condition holds but the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is zero is $m_n\sim(n\log n)^n$. Then Carleman's theorem shows the moments problem has a unique solution while the approach based on what you call the Hadamard radius fails.